# RGB to HSD Transformation

Tags: python, colors

I am following a [paper](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/227785918_Hue-saturation-density_HSD_model_for_stain_recognition_in_digital_images_from_transmitted_light_microscopy) in which they transform medical slide from RGB to HSD (hue-saturation-density). The hue and saturation channels are the same as in HSV but the density is computed using the channel densities D_ch:

[image: Density calculations]

where the numerator represents the intensity of a channel ch (R, G or B) and the denominator represents the intensity of channel ch when no stain is present.

I am unsure how to obtain the I_{0,ch}. Do I just sample all/some background pixels and average their intensities? If so, do I then have to repeatedly estimate the I_{0,ch} for each slide? I am doing this in Python.

Comment: You need get an accurate estimate of the intensity of channels when no stain is present. How to do this will depend on the actual source and layout of the image data. If you can identify background pixels then averaging a representative sample them might be good enough. If not, then it would be nice if there was some kind of a baseline slide with no stain on it that that could be used. As to whether this has to be done for each slide would depend of whether there was significantly variation of this from one slide to another.

Comment: @martineau: Your comment sounds like an answer rather than a comment.

Comment: @PeterO.: More like an educated guess…mixed with a few years of computer graphics experience. `;¬)`